Reverse SSH Tunnel from ESXI Client to a vServer to access OpenSlides
Hello there sorry for my bad english as it is not my native language,
I want to access a Docker application called OpenSlides from a ESXI Server that is currently blocked by the Firewall from my University. To circumvent this, I want to use a vServer that is publicly accessible for the reverse SSH Tunnel. Furthermore I wanted to install something like Nginx Proxy Manager on the ESXI Server and all the traffic will be forwarded to the vServer so that I can access the ESXI Server with a dedicated Domainname. I didn't choose to install it on the vServer because there was already a docker application called wiki.js. The default Port of OpenSlides is 8000. OpenSlides is a docker-compose application so is wiki.js if it's relevant.
I would appreciate any help (ChatGPT didn't help me that much)
